# Dockerfile build RUN: "file not found"

Tags: windows, docker, dockerfile, docker-build

Hello everyone i'm having issues with building the [dockerfile](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RasaHQ/paraphraser/main/Dockerfile.cpu)  following this guide to run a python model for paraphrasing https://github.com/RasaHQ/paraphraser,i'm new to docker but it seems like it can't find the download_model.sh, here's the error:

```
#10 sha256:94d3f967690340f8c35c43a1702fb522b42c465dd3f39622a5548afc2aac5b2c  
#10 0.470 /bin/sh: 1: /home/download_model.sh: not found  
#10 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c /home/download_model.sh]: exit code: 127
```

i think the problem lies in this section of the dockerfile:

```
  WORKDIR /home

  COPY download_model.sh download_model.sh
  RUN ./download_model.sh
```

I thought about adding this command in the dockerfile RUN dir:

```
  WORKDIR /home
  
  COPY download_model.sh download_model.sh
  RUN dir
  RUN ./download_model.sh
```

printing the following:

```
#10 [ 6/14] RUN dir
#10 sha256:3897e950f0add18c4f3eb3d7beba427134c711ea110c040575accdf1feddf627
#10 0.527 download_model.sh
#10 DONE 0.6s
```

is this print refering to what's inside /home in the image? if so download_model.sh should be there, than why it's not finding it when running the command `RUN ./download_model.sh` ?

i've already tried to replace the separator, replacing `CRLF` to `LF` did the tric opening the file on visual studio, but didn't do anything

thanks

Comment: Do you have the whole Dockerfile; what is the `FROM` line?  What is the very very first line of the script?  It sounds like you're on a Windows host, are you _sure_ the line endings are correct when you run `docker build`?

Comment: Hello, if you follow the link to the repository you can find the dockerfile.gpu, i've also added the direct link in the question.  i'm on a windows host and i'm running on the terminal the following: `docker build -f Dockerfile.cpu -t paraphraser_cpu:latest . `. What should i do to check the line endings? not really sure what to do, new to docker, thanks!

Comment: very first line: FROM ubuntu:20.04, and i'm targeting the linux deamon on docker desktop

Answer (score 0):

I still can't figure out what's specifically wrong, however since `download_model.sh` basically downloads a `.tar` from a drive folder, i manually downloaded the file into the dockerfile root folder and added this line to the dockerfile: `COPY m39v1.tar ./` to copy the model into the docker.

Still looking forward to someone with a proper solution!